# Virtual Shadow Depth Cube Texture (VSDCT) without indirection texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow, opengl-3, linderdaum

I've implemented a [VSDCT demo](http://blog.linderdaum.com/2014/01/19/omnidirectional-shadows-and-vsdct) using this code to convert `vec3` light directions within a cube map (as discribed in 8.13 Cube Map Texture Selection of [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf)) into `vec2` UV texture coordinates within a virtual texture:

```
vec2 GetShadowTC( vec3 Dir )
{
    float Sc;
    float Tc;
    float Ma;
    int FaceIndex;

    float rx = Dir.x;
    float ry = Dir.y;
    float rz = Dir.z;

    vec3 adir = abs(Dir);
    Ma = max( max( adir.x, adir.y ), adir.z );

    // -X +X ok
    if ( adir.x > adir.y && adir.x > adir.z )
    {
        Sc = ( rx > 0 ) ? rz : -rz;
        Tc = ry;
        FaceIndex = ( rx > 0 ) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    // -Y +Y ok
    else if ( adir.y > adir.x && adir.y > adir.z )
    {
        Sc = rx;
        Tc = ( ry > 0 ) ? rz : -rz;
        FaceIndex = ( ry > 0 ) ? 2 : 3;
    }
    // -Z +Z ok
    else
    {
        Sc = ( rz > 0 ) ? -rx : rx;
        Tc = ry;
        FaceIndex = ( rz > 0 ) ? 4 : 5;
    }

    float s = 0.5 * ( Sc / Ma + 1.0 );
    float t = 0.5 * ( Tc / Ma + 1.0 );

/*
    Calculate texture coordinates for faces in our 3x2 layout:
        0   1   2
        3   4   5
*/
    s = s / 3.0;
    t = t / 2.0;

    s += float(FaceIndex % 3 ) / 3.0;
    t += float(FaceIndex / 3 ) / 2.0;

    return vec2( s, t );
}
```

**This code works fine. However, I have two questions:**

1) Is there a way to reduce filtering artifacts between the cube map faces (which are laid out on a 3x2 virtual texture)?

2) Is it possible to make this code faster without using indirection texture (i.e, by clever using a ternary operator)?

Comment: I don't think I can answer either of your questions. Are there good reasons for keeping the shadow map in a 2D texture instead of a Cube texture (and avoiding both issues)?

Comment: @GuyRT: single render target, no framebuffer switches, lack of render-to-cubemap on mobiles.

Comment: I think you can render to cubemaps since ES 2.0, and I think swapping cube faces attached to a framebuffer should be quite cheap. I'm sure I'm missing something as it seems to be quite a popular technique, so feel free to ignore as I'm not helping you with your actual question :-)

Comment: @GuyRT: seems like nobody here is interested in VSDCT. Ok, maybe you can just craft an answer how to make a render-to-cubemap instead?